# Problems updating wordpress

Tags: upgrade, updates

When I try to update wordpress from 3.2.1 to the latest one it stalls and does nothing. It used to ask for my ftp details, which I looked up online and added this to the wp-config:

```
/** Setup FTP Details **/
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", "your-ftp-username");
define("FTP_PASS", "your-ftp-password");
```

This seems to have stopped it asking for ftp details, but it gets to a page and just does nothing, below is a screen shot of what I see. Any ideas of whats going wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: Where are they?

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting env...probably somewhere in your docroot. If you have a linux install using apache try looking in /etc/apache2/

Comment: error_log has nothing in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding all of the following:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
#define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
#define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

This is sourced from the official wp-config document [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants).

Comment: unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @RyanMurphy You will need to take a look at your folder permissions and make sure your Apache user or group it belongs to can write to your directories.

Comment: i done a chmod 777 on folders etc and still didnt work

Comment: @RyanMurphy I would contact your host and see if they have any restrictions...